# Trim blank spaces from the right in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see the `trim` method in jQuery, but I can't find, in [its documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), how to trim blank spaces from only the right of the string.

As an example, if I have:

```
"foobar "        "foo "         " foo bar  "
```

Trimming the spaces from the right of the string results in:

```
"foobar"         "foo"          " foo bar"
```

Is there any method in jQuery to trim the spaces from the right? **I mean, something like `ltrim` and `rtrim`?**

Comment: There is no rtrim or ltrim in jQuery core. There are plugins or you can just use a basic reg exp to do it.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello . I think that's a little thing that can be improved in the newest versions of jQuery - will be very useful.

Comment: They are not going to add that to jQuery core. Proof: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9542

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a simple regex replace

```
string.replace(/\s+$/, '')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GrvQE/)

```
function rtrim(str){
    return str.replace(/\s+$/, '');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`jQuery` doesn't have the methods `ltrim` or `rtrim`.

You can do it easily:

```
function rtrim(str){
    return str.replace(/\s+$/, "");
}
function ltrim(str){
    return str.replace(/^\s+/, "");
}
```

I **don't** suggest you add a method on the `String` prototype.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
String.prototype.rtrim = function() {
    return this.replace(/\s+$/,"");
}

var str = "test ";
console.log(str.rtrim());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this too:

```
 "foobar ".substring(0,"foobar ".length-1)
```

I'm not really into jQuery so you may need to use

```
  var yourstring ="something ";
```

Comment: That means the dev would have to know the amount of whitespace. What if it is dynamic? This is not going to work.